# Algorithm to store 64 bit number represented by a string in two 32b registers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, mips, 32-bit

This is an assembly language problem.
I already figured out how to accept user input as a string and the convert it to integer

Multiply current sum by 10 (shift by 3 and shift by 1 position to the left then add two results together)and add new digit from the string (already converted to number by subtracting 48)

Now up until the point of overflow this would work fine, but then how does the number get split up to fit into two registers? Does it have to be divided or bit shifted? Please explain in details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will need to synthesize double-width operations, namely shifting and addition.

For the shift, apart from shifting both halves separately, you need to bring in the spilled top bits from the low half into the high half. For that you shift the low half right as appropriate then use bitwise `OR` or addition to put them into the high half.

In pseudocode (using logical shifts):

```
result_low = (orig_low << n)
result_high = (orig_high << n) | (orig low >> (32 - n))
```

For the addition, you process the low half then check if it is less than one of the original operands. If it is, that means an overflow occurred and you have to add the carry to the high half as well as the high half of the addend.

```
result_low = op1_low + op2_low
result_high = op1_high + op2_high + ((result_low < op1_low) ? 1 : 0)
```

A possible asm implementation:

```
    la $t2, buff            ; pointer to string
    li $t0, 0               ; low
    li $t1, 0               ; high
loop:
    lb $t3, ($t2)           ; load next byte
    beq $t3, $zero, done    ; end of string?
    addi $t3, $t3, -48      ; convert from ascii
                            ; t4,5 = t0,1 << 1
    srl $t6, $t0, 31        ; t6 is used for the spilled bit
    sll $t4, $t0, 1         ; shift low half
    sll $t5, $t1, 1         ; shift high half
    or $t5, $t5, $t6        ; put in the spilled bit
                            ; t0,1 <<= 3
    srl $t6, $t0, 29        ; the 3 spilled bits
    sll $t0, $t0, 3         ; shift low half
    sll $t1, $t1, 3         ; shift high half
    or $t1, $t1, $t6        ; put in the spilled bits
                            ; t0,1 += t4,5
    addu $t0, $t0, $t4      ; add low halves
    addu $t1, $t1, $t5      ; add high halves
    sltu $t6, $t0, $t4      ; t6 = (t0 < t4), that is the carry
    addu $t1, $t1, $t6      ; add the carry if any
                            ; ok t0,1 has been multiplied by 10
    addu $t0, $t0, $t3      ; just add the digit now
    sltu $t6, $t0, $t3      ; the carry
    addu $t1, $t1, $t6      ; add the carry if any

    addiu $t2, $t2, 1       ; increment pointer
    b loop                  ; and continue
done:
```

You could of course also directly use multiplication instead of shifts.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Now I will study the code and follow your logic. This literally saved me

Answer (score 0):

The number are bit shifted. 
You can refer the multiplication sequence given on wiki to get the idea how LO and HI registers are populated

```
LO = (($s * $t) << 32) >> 32;
HI = ($s * $t) >> 32;
```

[en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#section_6](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#section_6)